# XSD - if attribute a1 = 'true' then element <body> is required and should not be empty

Tags: xml, xsd

I try to solve following problem using pure XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to a1="true">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to a1="false">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
</note>
```

If attribute a1="true", then the body element is required and should not be empty.
The two XMLs above are valid, but these are not valid messages:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to a1="true">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
</note>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to a1="true">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body></body>
</note>
```

Any idea?
Thx a lot!

Comment: XSD 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: Cannot be done in XSD 1.0.  If you can use XSD 1.1, see duplicate link for example of how to use `xs:assertion` to make occurence dependent upon an attribute value.